# How to use componentDidUpdate with shouldComponentUpdate in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know,if shouldComponentUpdate return true componentDidUpdate will run..In my case I got infinite loop in chrome debugger session.This could lead to low performance.My main question is, How to actually use componentDidUpdate??

```
state = { 
    cartItems: [] 
}


componentDidMount() {
        this.getCart();
    }


getCart = async () => {
        let cart = await API.getCart();
        if (cart) {
            this.setState({
                loading: false,
                cartItems: cart
            })
        }
        console.log(cart) //for checking it in chrome debugger
    }



shouldComponentUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        return prevState.cartItems != this.state.cartItems
    }


componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (prevState.cartItems != this.state.cartItems) {
            this.getCart();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are checking 2 different things here: `return prevState.data != this.state.cartItems` is that intentional or mistake. They maynot match thus always returns true

Comment: @Rikin Nah.!  No matter, if I use prevState.data or prevState.cartItems , It definitely goes to infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem isn't `shouldComponentUpdate`. Is the following comparison in `componentDidUpdate`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.cartItems != this.state.cartItems) {
        this.getCart();
    }
}
```

This will always be `true` because of how arrays are compared, event if you used it with `!==` (which is the recommended way) the comparison will always evaluate to `true`.

- In `componentDidUpdate` you're calling `getCart` causing the component to update
- In `componentDidUpdate` you're calling `getCart` again, causing the component to update, calling `getCart` again and so on.

Either perform a `deep comparison` on each item of `cartItems`, or check the `length` property maybe (could work in some cases). Or if order doesn't matter you could use `JSON.stringify`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (JSON.stringify(prevState.cartItems) !== JSON.stringify(this.state.cartItems)) {
        this.getCart();
    }
}
```

To achieve the expected behavior ( re fetch everytime an item is added to `cartItems` you could do the following

```
class Cart extends React.Component{
    state = {
        items : []
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        getCart()
    }

    addItem = item =>{
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            items : prevState.items.concat(item)}
        ), this.getCart)
    }



    render(){
        return <button onClick={() => this.addItem('item')}>Add</button>
    }
}
```

By using the second argument of `setState` you're ensuring the changes in `state` are all done, once the `item` is added the component will fetch again, but this time without the loop

Comment: @Dupocas yes, the infinite loops gets stopped.but this time, the cart do not update itself.instead,I had to manually reload the whole app to refresh it.

Comment: What is the expected behavior? The component should update itself in an amount of seconds? When you want the data to be fetched again?

Comment: @Dupocas There are products in a product page.if I click add to cart button the cart should update in Cart Page..I just want whenever I click add to cart button Cart refreshes instead of me reloading or refreshing the whole app.

Comment: @Dupocas glad to hear.

Comment: Why is there Add button in there.In my case I have an two page..Product.js and Cart.js ....... I have an Add button in Product.js page ,when calling that button, function API.createCart() with arguments quantity and productId gets called and item should be Added to cart and there will be update in Cart.js Page without actually have to refresh the page.

Comment: So the `state` should be own by a parent wrapping `Cart` and `Products`

Comment: Ahh, I tell you what's actually going on in here.. I have a backend in nodejs where I've defined routes regarding product and cart..IN RN I've an function in Product.js Page..... addToCart = async () => {  await API.createCart({ productId: id, quantity: quantity, size: size })  } ..and Cart.js page is defined in the question.